# install custom pages in subdomain on creation using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating subdomains automatically using PHP using the following code. this code will create a sundomain based on the users input. so basically if user writes `test` in the input field and clicks the submit button, a subdomain with the name `test` will be created on my server!

Now, what I am trying to do is to install some pages (lets say a custom made index.php) on the subdomains created by the users immediately after it has been created.

**is this possible using PHP alone and if so, how can I do that?**

**Here is the code that creates the subdomains:**

```
<?php
//Set the name for your New Sub Domain
$subDomainname= $_POST['userInput'];

//cPanel Username
$cPanelUserName="XXXXXXXX";

//cPanel Password
$cPanelPassName="XXXXXXXXXX";

//Main Domain Name
$rootDomainName="XXXXXXXXXXX";

        //Function to create subdomain
function create_subdomain($subDomain,$cPanelUser,$cPanelPass,$rootDomain) {

    //Generate URL for access the subdomain creation in cPanel through PHP
    $buildRequest = "/frontend/x3/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=" . $rootDomain . "&domain=" . $subDomain . "&dir=public_html/subdomains/" . $subDomain;

    //Open the socket
    $openSocket = fsockopen('localhost',2082);
    if(!$openSocket) {
        //SHow error
        return "Socket error";
        exit();
    }

    //Login Details
    $authString = $cPanelUser . ":" . $cPanelPass;

    //Encrypt the Login Details 
    $authPass = base64_encode($authString);

    //Request to Server using GET method
    $buildHeaders  = "GET " . $buildRequest ."\r\n";

    //HTTP
    $buildHeaders .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    //Define Host
    $buildHeaders .= "Host:localhost\r\n";

    //Request Authorization
    $buildHeaders .= "Authorization: Basic " . $authPass . "\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "\r\n";

    //fputs
    fputs($openSocket, $buildHeaders);
    while(!feof($openSocket)) {
    fgets($openSocket,128);
    }
    fclose($openSocket);

    //Return the New SUbdomain with full URL
    $newDomain = "http://" . $subDomain . "." . $rootDomain . "/";

    //return with Message

}

//Call the subdomain creator function
echo create_subdomain($subDomainname,$cPanelUserName,$cPanelPassName,$rootDomainName);
?>
```

Comment: @TheBlueDog, I run my own hosting company. please either answer the question directly or keep away if you are not going to contribute in a right way.

Comment: Whatever you say, boss.

Comment: thanks midget :D just kidding

Comment: ;) Well, you'd need to do a [mkdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) for the new user and [copy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) an HTML template file to it. Don't forget to assign the correct permissions for the new user to their directory. That's probably over-simplifying it, but you get the drift...

Comment: It is interesting, that as a 'hosting company' owner that you don't seem to be aware that 'user domain names' map to 'disk directories'. And creating those is mentioned in the PHP manual here: **[function.mkdir](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)**. Also, as you own the server there is no need to go through 'cpanel' to do what you want as you have easy access to everything. A few simple scripts will do it.